# Is it possible to run multiple instances of the same sub, or is refactoring necessary?

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Screenshot of Incompatible Switches]

**Expected Result**

The Claim Removal switches above are incompatible with the HL Segment Numbering switch. If the user turns the HL Segment Numbering switch On while one or both of the Claim Removal switches are already On, the Claim Removal Switches will be turned off, and vice versa.

---

I am trying to efficiently use one `Sub`, `Toggle_Click`, to manage turning switches on and off, and another, `Toggle_ErrorPrevention`, to prevent two incompatible switches from being turned on at the same time.

The issue I'm having trouble with is that when `Toggle_ErrorPrevention` tries to turn off an incompatible switch by calling `Toggle_Click` via `Application.Run .Shapes([incompatible switch]).OnAction`, `Toggle_Click` does not recognize the incompatible switch as the new `Application.Caller`, believing it instead to be the original switch that started the whole sequence.

This may be because `Toggle_Click` is still mid-execution from the first call and VBA is not able to recognize a new caller until the first call finishes.

How can I get `Toggle_Click` to recognize [incompatible switch] as a new `Application.Caller`?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Toggle_Click()
    Dim lngMoveBy As Long
    Dim Loop1 As Long
    Dim intShapeNumber As Integer
    Dim boolActive As Boolean

    '--- A user clicked a toggle or Toggle_ErrPrevention is trying to turn off an incompatible toggle ---
    'Which toggle triggered this sub? Get ready to turn that toggle on/off
    intShapeNumber = Right(Application.Caller, Len(Application.Caller) - Len("Toggle"))
    'Is the toggle inactive (white)?
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Correction Type Options").Shapes("ToggleBackground" & intShapeNumber).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255) Then boolActive = False Else boolActive = True
    'A user-clicked toggle that is currently off may have incompatible toggles that are currently on. If currently off, prevent errors
    'If Toggle_ErrPrevention is trying to turn off an incompatible toggle, it won't trigger itself again because incompatible toggles are always on
    If boolActive = False Then Toggle_ErrorPrevention intShapeNumber

    '--- The triggering toggle was on or all incompatible toggles have been turned off. Get ready to change triggering toggle state ---
    'Which direction should the switch graphic be moved?
    If boolActive = False Then
        'Move right to On position
        lngMoveBy = 0.6
    Else
        'Move left to Off position
        lngMoveBy = -0.6
    End If

    'Actually move the switch graphic in the appropriate direction
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Correction Type Options").Shapes("Toggle" & intShapeNumber)
        For Loop1 = 1 To 24
            .IncrementLeft lngMoveBy
            DoEvents
        Next Loop1
    End With

    'Change switch text and color
    If boolActive = False Then
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Correction Type Options").Shapes("ToggleBackground" & intShapeNumber)
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            .TextFrame.Characters.Text = "On"
            .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Bold = True
            .TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 1
            .TextFrame.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
            .TextFrame.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
    Else
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Correction Type Options").Shapes("ToggleBackground" & intShapeNumber)
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            .TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Off"
            .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Bold = True
            .TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 1
            .TextFrame.HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
            .TextFrame.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
    End If

End Sub

Sub Toggle_ErrorPrevention(ByVal intShapeNumberVal As Integer)

    Dim lngHLSegmentNumberingRow As Long
    Dim lngClaimRemovalHaveWantedClaimsRow As Long
    Dim lngClaimRemovalHaveUnwantedClaimsRow As Long


    'Find current location of incompatible switches
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Correction Type Options").Columns(1)
        lngHLSegmentNumberingRow = .Find(What:="HL Segment Numbering", Lookat:=xlWhole).Row
        lngClaimRemovalHaveWantedClaimsRow = .Find(What:="Claim Removal - Have Wanted Claims", Lookat:=xlWhole).Row
        lngClaimRemovalHaveUnwantedClaimsRow = .Find(What:="Claim Removal - Have Unwanted Claims", Lookat:=xlWhole).Row
    End With

    'If an incompatible switch is green (on), run Toggle_Click for the incompatible switch
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Correction Type Options")
        'Claim Removal is incompatible with HL Segment Numbering
        If intShapeNumberVal + 1 = lngHLSegmentNumberingRow Then
            If .Shapes("ToggleBackground" & lngClaimRemovalHaveWantedClaimsRow - 1).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0) Then Application.Run .Shapes("Toggle" & lngClaimRemovalHaveWantedClaimsRow - 1).OnAction
            If .Shapes("ToggleBackground" & lngClaimRemovalHaveUnwantedClaimsRow - 1).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0) Then Application.Run .Shapes("Toggle" & lngClaimRemovalHaveUnwantedClaimsRow - 1).OnAction
        End If
        'HL Segment Numbering is incompatible with Claim Removal
        If intShapeNumberVal + 1 = lngClaimRemovalHaveWantedClaimsRow Or intShapeNumberVal + 1 = lngClaimRemovalHaveUnwantedClaimsRow Then
            If .Shapes("ToggleBackground" & lngHLSegmentNumberingRow - 1).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0) Then Application.Run .Shapes("Toggle" & lngHLSegmentNumberingRow - 1).OnAction
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey. Can you include a screenshot of your worksheet and also what behaviour you expect to see?

Comment: @CallumDA I added lots of comments to the code and added a screenshot, hopefully that will help. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, I'll update my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below toggles your three shapes like this:

[image] [image] [image] [image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub ToggleShape()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Dim selectedShape As Shape
        Set selectedShape = .Shapes(Application.Caller)

        'always turn on selected shape
        FormatShape selectedShape, "On"

        'turn off relevant other shapes
        Select Case selectedShape.Name
            Case "ToggleBackground1"
                FormatShape .Shapes("ToggleBackground2"), "Off"
                FormatShape .Shapes("ToggleBackground3"), "Off"
            Case Else
                FormatShape .Shapes("ToggleBackground1"), "Off"
        End Select
    End With
End Sub

Sub FormatShape(sh As Shape, status As String)
    With sh
        If status = "On" Then
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            .TextFrame.Characters.Text = "On"
        Else
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            .TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Off"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I know you were waiting for me to get my edits up, but one reason this won't work is because I don't want a switched turned on unnecessarily, only turned off if necessary. Let me know if I can clarify my original question any better - I'm about to format the expected results section to make it more visible.

Comment: Hey @puzzlepiece87, I updated my answer - let me know how you get on?

Comment: Oh, I get it, you're basically suggesting I use three `Sub`s instead of two: `Toggle_Click_Trigger`, `Toggle_Click_Formatting`, and `Toggle_ErrPrevention` that calls `Toggle_Click_Formatting` with arguments to avoid over-relying on `Application.Caller`. I like it, thank you!

Comment: Well, do you really need the `Toggle_ErrPrevention` sub? But yes, you definitely don't want to overuse `Application.Caller`. I reworked my answer a bit just to make it slightly more obvious how it's working :) Anyway, pleased to help!

Comment: You are right, I don't need it. Your edit helped clear that up. Thanks!